# Create Application Users whenever a new participant is created by the admin

Tags: angularjs, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created a composer business model with an angular web application. What I want to do is whenever the admin creates new participant, login credentials should be created for the user to log in (saved in database) to the application later on.

I know that I have to use multi-user mode, and also should issue identity for the participant (i can do that through command line) but how this should be done through the angular application?

To make things more clear, what I want to know is as follow :

1. How to issue identity for the participant through the angular application?
2. How to link between application users and the participants created in the network?
   Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Where are the credentials stored (after being created by the Admin)?

Comment: It will be saved in a separate database, what I really want to achieve is to know how to issue identitity (card) to the created participants through the angular web application

Comment: Still, not clear, but let's see... In order to provide the credentials to the new user, he/she needs to identify himself/herself to the system to make sure you are providing them to the right person, right? How is he/she going to do that? Normally, the registering person would provide an e-mail address or a mobile phone number and the system would send the username and a temporary password. That way you are closing the loop.

Comment: 1) see example of using REST APIs from angular to create identities -> https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc 2) your app user names can map to your participant names (whether directly or as a mapping) in the business network (participants are linked to one (or more) blockchain identities, issued as described)